# How to customize bootstrap-vue dropdown menu using bootstrap-vue icon?

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, datatable, icons, bootstrap-vue

I am working with vue js and bootstrap-vue. I am tring to implement bootstrap vue datatables.In the table I want to use dropdownt using tree-dot-vertical icon in the action column.
Here my table view..

[My table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYB7D.png)

In the above table the iconic dropdown menu in the action column there are two icon .One is three dot vertical icon and the other is arrow sign. I want to remove the arrow sign and border from the dropdown menu.

Here the code for dropdown menu..

```html
<template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
  <div>
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" variant="outline-info">
      <template #button-content>
        <b-icon
          icon="three-dots-vertical"
          aria-hidden="true"
        ></b-icon>
      </template>

      <b-dropdown-item
        variant="primary"
        :to="{
          name: 'QuizEditPage',
          params: { id: data.item.id },
        }"
        >Edit</b-dropdown-item
      >
      <b-dropdown-item
        variant="danger"
        @click="deleteQuiz(data.item.id)"
        >Delete</b-dropdown-item
      >
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can solve the proble?Please help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `no-caret` to `<b-dropdown>`?

Comment: No,I have not used that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `no-caret` solves your problem.

Note that you can replace `<custom-icon />` with `<b-icon icon='three-dots-vertical' />`

```js
Vue.component('customIcon', {
  template: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15.352" height="15.355" viewBox="0 0 15.352 15.355">
        <path id="Union_19" data-name="Union 19" d="M-19.5-15958.5l-7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5Z" transform="translate(27.176 15966.178)" fill="none" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    </svg>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown no-caret>
    <template #button-content>
        Custom Dropdown
        <custom-icon /> // or any other icons for example b-icon
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```